# Electric flux calculation through projected area

Tags: electrostatics

Suppose we have an unit sphere centered at (1,1,1) and there is an electric field:
$$E = 400\hat{\imath} + 400\hat{\jmath}$$
We are supposed to find the electric flux due to the electric field through the region $x>1,y>1,z>1$ (i.e., the topmost octant of the sphere).How do I find the *projected area* in this case and thus, calculate the electric flux?(I'm just a 12th grade student and I know nothing of surface integrals and advanced calculus!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is clearly asking for flux through given surface which is first octant of a sphere of radius 1 unit.
You can find this flux by using the fact that net flux through a closed surface is zero. Consider your 3 dimensional object to be a ball in first octant. Now it is clear that flux through planes x and y and z is equal to flux through curved part of sphere. So you can calculate it by multiplying E field component with area vector comoponent which is 1/4 of area of circle.

Comment: flux through closed surface is not zero, the sphere is not a conductor

Comment: The net flux would be zero since electric field lines do enter the sphere, but they would also be leaving through the other surface, resulting in net zero flux.

Comment: Harsh Nigam can you please elaborate on how to find the area vector component parallel to the electric field?

Comment: @AbhinavTahlani net flux is not zero the field lines would be passing through 2- d circle area, I hope you get it now

Comment: But field lines entering through a 2d circle must also leave through another 2d circle due to symmetry. Shouldn't the net flux be zero? Incoming and outgoing flux should have the same magnitude, but they are in the opposite sense, so they must cancel each other out.

Comment: @Abhinav Tahlani field lines are continuous ,definition and concept of flux refers to field lines passing through area ,not that the field lines are leaving or entering through an area

Comment: @maverick I think I have not clearly written it but you have also not clearly understood that which point i missed.point is that net flux through a closed surface is zero if volume enclosed by gaussian surface do not contain a source /sink.

Comment: @AbhinavTahlani I see maverick has explained ur problem related to area vector in below comment. Just adding to that for taking direction of area vector just use right hand curl rule. In given case according to standard convention for xy plane direction perpe dicular to it z is taken as direction of area vector similarly for yz plane direction x is direction area vector.

Answer (score 3):

$Ф=E_x\times S_x +E_y\times S_y$ where $S_x=S_y=\frac{\pi R^2}{4}$

Comment: You take the projection of the surface perpendicular to the field.

Comment: That's exactly where I'm facing the problem! Can you please elaborate on how to find the projection of the surface perpendicular to the field?

Comment: It is a quarter of the biggest circle of a sphere.

Comment: @Abhinav Tahlani imagine you are viewing sphere from outside, you would see it like a circle, view it from x axis then from y axis, you would view octant of sphere  as quarter of 2-d circle from outside , on more imagination you would find this quarter of circle  perpendicular to fields

Comment: I get it now! The projection of a sphere gives a circle in 2d, and our required octant is 1/4th of that circle. Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The reference was really helpful.